# SVG анимация блик элемента

Tags: css, html5, svg, анимация, css-animation

Как при наведении на `SVG`-элемент реализовать эффект блика (когда осветлённый градиент проходит через весь элемент). Желательно без `SMIL` анимации, чтобы анимация касалась, как иконки, так и текста.

```css
.game_block__play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  width: 300px;
  height: 110px;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  transition: .2s all;
}

.game_block__play svg {
  fill: #FE20A4;
  stroke: #2F0E3D;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10
}

.game_block__play text {
  font-size: 74px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  transform: translate(110px, 84px);
}
```

```html
<button class="game_block__play" type="button" title="Play">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 110">
    <g id="">
      <path d="M55.5 2C26.3 2 2.7 25.7 2.7 54.8s23.7 52.8 52.8 52.8 52.8-23.7 52.8-52.8S84.7 2 55.5 2zM31 98.6c-21.4-9-16.1-84.1 2-87.1 0 0 43.3-9.7 71.3 39.4 12.9 22.6-57.4 54.4-73.3 47.7z"/>
      <path d="M89.8 57.7l-48.1 27c-2.2 1.2-4.9-.3-4.9-2.7V27.8c0-2.5 2.7-4.1 4.9-2.7l48.2 27.1c2.1 1.2 2.1 4.2-.1 5.5z"/>
    </g>
    <text>PLAY</text>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Можно какой-то чисто визуальный пример?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Анимация градиента в зоне действия треугольного значка

Для адаптивности перенёс кнопку из `css` в `svg`. Обернул `svg` контейнером `<div class="container">` При такой схеме вёрстки кнопку с анимационными эффектами можно вставить в любое место страницы HTML и позиционировать, масштабировать по мере своей необходимости.

**Анимация начинается по клику `begin="svg1.click"` при желании можно сделать по наведению курсора `begin="svg1.mouseover"`**

```css
.container {
 width:25%;
 height:25%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 350 125">
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="33%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="67%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform"
        type="translate"
        from="-1 0"
        to="1 0"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="0.8s"
        repeatCount="1"
        restartWhenNotActive
        fill="freeze"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs> 
   <g id="btn" stroke="gray" fill="#FE20A4" >
    <rect class="game_block__play" x="4" y="4" width="320" height="112" rx="15" fill="transparent"  stroke-width="2" />
 <text class="txt1" x="125" y="84" font-size="72px" font-family="Arial, sans-serif"  >PLAY</text>
   </g> 
    <g id="triangle" transform="translate(10 5)" stroke="gray" fill="url(#linear-gradient)" >
      <path  d="M55.5 2C26.3 2 2.7 25.7 2.7 54.8s23.7 52.8 52.8 52.8 52.8-23.7 52.8-52.8S84.7 2 55.5 2zM31 98.6c-21.4-9-16.1-84.1 2-87.1 0 0 43.3-9.7 71.3 39.4 12.9 22.6-57.4 54.4-73.3 47.7z"/>
      <path  d="M89.8 57.7l-48.1 27c-2.2 1.2-4.9-.3-4.9-2.7V27.8c0-2.5 2.7-4.1 4.9-2.7l48.2 27.1c2.1 1.2 2.1 4.2-.1 5.5z"/>
    </g>
 
  </svg>
  </div>
```

### Анимация градиента в зоне действия треугольного значка плюс буквы

*Анимация в этом примере и в других, которые ниже начинается после клика на кнопке `begin="svg1.click"` при желании можно сделать по наведению курсора `begin="svg1.mouseover"`*

```css
.container {
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 350 125" >
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" >
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform"
        type="translate"
        values="-1 0;1 0"       
     fill="freeze"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="1s"
        repeatCount="1"
  restartWhenNotActive/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs> 
   <g id="btn" stroke="gray"   fill="url(#linear-gradient)">
    <rect class="game_block__play" x="4" y="4" width="320" height="112" rx="15" fill="transparent"  stroke-width="2" />
 <text class="txt1" x="125" y="84" font-size="72px" font-family="Arial, sans-serif"  >PLAY</text>
   
    <g id="triangle" transform="translate(10 5)" stroke="gray" fill="url(#linear-gradient)" >
      <path  d="M55.5 2C26.3 2 2.7 25.7 2.7 54.8s23.7 52.8 52.8 52.8 52.8-23.7 52.8-52.8S84.7 2 55.5 2zM31 98.6c-21.4-9-16.1-84.1 2-87.1 0 0 43.3-9.7 71.3 39.4 12.9 22.6-57.4 54.4-73.3 47.7z"/>
      <path  d="M89.8 57.7l-48.1 27c-2.2 1.2-4.9-.3-4.9-2.7V27.8c0-2.5 2.7-4.1 4.9-2.7l48.2 27.1c2.1 1.2 2.1 4.2-.1 5.5z"/>
    </g>
</g>  
   
  </svg>
</div>
```

Изменяем цветовую гамму, - **чёрно-белый вариант**, для этого меняем значения в атрибутах градиента `stop-color`

```css
.container {
 width:45%;
 height:45%;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 350 125">
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" >
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="30%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" />
 <!--  <set attributeName="gradientTransform"  type="translate" values="1 0;-1 0"  begin="0s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze"/> -->
   
      <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform"
        type="translate"
        values="-1 0;1 0"       
     fill="freeze"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="1s"
        repeatCount="1"
  restartWhenNotActive/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs> 
   <g id="btn" stroke="gray"   fill="url(#linear-gradient)">
    <rect class="game_block__play" x="4" y="4" width="320" height="112" rx="15" fill="transparent"  stroke-width="2" />
 <text class="txt1" x="125" y="84" font-size="72px" font-family="Arial, sans-serif"  >PLAY</text>
   
    <g id="triangle" transform="translate(10 5)" stroke="gray" fill="url(#linear-gradient)" >
      <path  d="M55.5 2C26.3 2 2.7 25.7 2.7 54.8s23.7 52.8 52.8 52.8 52.8-23.7 52.8-52.8S84.7 2 55.5 2zM31 98.6c-21.4-9-16.1-84.1 2-87.1 0 0 43.3-9.7 71.3 39.4 12.9 22.6-57.4 54.4-73.3 47.7z"/>
      <path  d="M89.8 57.7l-48.1 27c-2.2 1.2-4.9-.3-4.9-2.7V27.8c0-2.5 2.7-4.1 4.9-2.7l48.2 27.1c2.1 1.2 2.1 4.2-.1 5.5z"/>
    </g>
</g>  
   
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Чёрно-желтый вариант**

```css
 .container {
 width:45%;
 height:45%;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 350 125">
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" >
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="30%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellow" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" />
 <!--  <set attributeName="gradientTransform"  type="translate" values="1 0;-1 0"  begin="0s" dur="0.2s" fill="freeze"/> -->
   
      <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform"
        type="translate"
        values="-1 0;1 0"       
     fill="freeze"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="1s"
        repeatCount="1"
  restartWhenNotActive/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs> 
   <g id="btn" stroke="gray"   fill="url(#linear-gradient)">
    <rect class="game_block__play" x="4" y="4" width="320" height="112" rx="15" fill="transparent"  stroke-width="2" />
 <text class="txt1" x="125" y="84" font-size="72px" font-family="Arial, sans-serif"  >PLAY</text>
   
    <g id="triangle" transform="translate(10 5)" stroke="gray" fill="url(#linear-gradient)" >
      <path  d="M55.5 2C26.3 2 2.7 25.7 2.7 54.8s23.7 52.8 52.8 52.8 52.8-23.7 52.8-52.8S84.7 2 55.5 2zM31 98.6c-21.4-9-16.1-84.1 2-87.1 0 0 43.3-9.7 71.3 39.4 12.9 22.6-57.4 54.4-73.3 47.7z"/>
      <path  d="M89.8 57.7l-48.1 27c-2.2 1.2-4.9-.3-4.9-2.7V27.8c0-2.5 2.7-4.1 4.9-2.7l48.2 27.1c2.1 1.2 2.1 4.2-.1 5.5z"/>
    </g>
</g>  
   
  </svg>
</div>
```

### Диагональный градиент

Для этого добавляем в определение градиента:

`<linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%">`

**Анимация только значка**

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 350 125" >
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="43%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform"
        type="translate"
        values="-1 0;1 0"       
     fill="freeze"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="0.5s"
        repeatCount="1"
  restartWhenNotActive/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs> 
   <g id="btn" stroke="gray" fill="#FE20A4" >
    <rect class="game_block__play" x="4" y="4" width="320" height="112" rx="15" fill="transparent"  stroke-width="2" />
 <text class="txt1" x="125" y="84" font-size="72px" font-family="Arial, sans-serif"  >PLAY</text>
   </g> 
    <g id="triangle" transform="translate(10 5)" stroke="gray" fill="url(#linear-gradient)" >
      <path  d="M55.5 2C26.3 2 2.7 25.7 2.7 54.8s23.7 52.8 52.8 52.8 52.8-23.7 52.8-52.8S84.7 2 55.5 2zM31 98.6c-21.4-9-16.1-84.1 2-87.1 0 0 43.3-9.7 71.3 39.4 12.9 22.6-57.4 54.4-73.3 47.7z"/>
      <path  d="M89.8 57.7l-48.1 27c-2.2 1.2-4.9-.3-4.9-2.7V27.8c0-2.5 2.7-4.1 4.9-2.7l48.2 27.1c2.1 1.2 2.1 4.2-.1 5.5z"/>
    </g>
   
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Анимация значка и букв**

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 350 125" >
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="43%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FE20A4" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform"
        type="translate"
        values="-1 0;1 0"       
     fill="freeze"
        begin="svg1.click"
        dur="0.5s"
        repeatCount="1"
  restartWhenNotActive/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs> 
   <g id="btn" stroke="gray" fill="url(#linear-gradient)" >
    <rect class="game_block__play" x="4" y="4" width="320" height="112" rx="15" fill="transparent"  stroke-width="2" />
 <text class="txt1" x="125" y="84" font-size="72px" font-family="Arial, sans-serif"  >PLAY</text>
    
    <g id="triangle" transform="translate(10 5)" stroke="gray"  >
      <path  d="M55.5 2C26.3 2 2.7 25.7 2.7 54.8s23.7 52.8 52.8 52.8 52.8-23.7 52.8-52.8S84.7 2 55.5 2zM31 98.6c-21.4-9-16.1-84.1 2-87.1 0 0 43.3-9.7 71.3 39.4 12.9 22.6-57.4 54.4-73.3 47.7z"/>
      <path  d="M89.8 57.7l-48.1 27c-2.2 1.2-4.9-.3-4.9-2.7V27.8c0-2.5 2.7-4.1 4.9-2.7l48.2 27.1c2.1 1.2 2.1 4.2-.1 5.5z"/>
    </g>
   </g> 
   
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Пример

```css
.game_block__play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  width: 300px;
  height: 110px;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  transition: .2s all;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.game_block__play svg {
  fill: #FE20A4;
  stroke: #2F0E3D;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10
}

.game_block__play text {
  font-size: 74px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  transform: translate(110px, 84px);
}

.game_block__play:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -75%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 100%);
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
}

.game_block__play:hover:before {
  animation: blick 1.25s forwards;
}

@keyframes blick {
  100% {
    left: 125%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="game_block__play" type="button" title="Play">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 110">
    <g id="">
      <path d="M55.5 2C26.3 2 2.7 25.7 2.7 54.8s23.7 52.8 52.8 52.8 52.8-23.7 52.8-52.8S84.7 2 55.5 2zM31 98.6c-21.4-9-16.1-84.1 2-87.1 0 0 43.3-9.7 71.3 39.4 12.9 22.6-57.4 54.4-73.3 47.7z"/>
      <path d="M89.8 57.7l-48.1 27c-2.2 1.2-4.9-.3-4.9-2.7V27.8c0-2.5 2.7-4.1 4.9-2.7l48.2 27.1c2.1 1.2 2.1 4.2-.1 5.5z"/>
    </g>
    <text>PLAY</text>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересный эффект вышел, а возможно ли, реализовать что б данный блик распространялся только на SVG элементы ? Дело в том, что если кнопке поставить другой фон, допустим зеленый, или под кнопкой положить картинку, то выглядеть оно будет уже не так классно